# Lubridate not converting datetime to POSIXct correctly in R (dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss)

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I'm trying to convert my datetime from a csv to POSIXct for data analysis. I've tried multiple codes but either get NA or a wrong format.

The code I'm currently using is

```
GRS$datetimelocal<- 
 GRS$`datetime` %>%
 ymd_hms(tz="UTC") %>% # first convert the `Date and Time (UTC)` 
 column into a 'POSIX' format 
 with_tz(tzone="Australia/Brisbane") # convert to local 
"Australia/Brisbane" date time (UTC + 10hrs)
```

My datetime column is in the format dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss.

```
datetime
26/03/2013 21:50
26/03/2013 21:56
26/03/2013 21:58
28/03/2013 07:42
```

However the new column spits out as

```
datetimelocal 
2026-03-20 13:21:50
2026-03-20 13:21:56
2026-03-20 13:21:58
2028-03-20 13:07:42
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: instead of `ymd_hms` use `dmy_hm`

Comment: ah perfect thank you. I thought I had tried that before but may I added dmy_hms instead. Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `as.POSIXct` directly?

```
as.POSIXct("26/03/2013 21:50", 
           format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", 
           tz = "Australia/Brisbane")
## [1] "2013-03-26 21:50:00 AEST"
```